# Chrome - weird "new tab" screen

Tags: google-chrome

I'm looking to find help on why Chrome is giving me this weird screen. Whenever I open a new tab it doesn't show the familiar Chrome apps, with the option to view tabs open on other devices in the bottom right. This started happening about a couple weeks ago. I have uninstalled Chrome and it comes back when I re-install it.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image: Chrome new tab screen]

Comment: That's the new "New" tab. http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/01/google-chrome-redesign-new-tab-page-rolls-out-to-all/

Comment: Oh, I hate it ha! How do I see tabs open on other devices now?

Comment: Open the hamburger menu and open "Recent Tabs". It'll show you tabs you've recently closed in the current browser as well as those on other devices.